# Aggregate large number of observables into new observable

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I have, let's say, a 1000 observables. Now I want to aggregate all the events into a new observable that fires OnNext once all the others have sent an event. Whats the best way to do that using Rx?

**Update**:
Some great feedback over at the Rx forum, especially by Dave Sexton. He showed how to create a Zip extension method that takes multiple observables: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/daaa84db-b560-4eda-871e-e523098db20c/

Comment: Are all the types of the 1000 observables the same?  What do you type of the aggregating observable to be?

Comment: All the 1000 observables are the same type, the new aggregate can be a new type. E.g. Event becomes AggregateEvent.

Comment: Do you want to combine their latest values only?  I.E. if Observable a fires two events and Observable b fires only one, do you want to aggregate the first event from a, or the last event from a, with b's event?

Comment: @Richard Hein  Lets start with taking the last event from a since we can assume that they arrive in order, i.e. all 1000 events arrive before some observables fire new events. BUT it would be of course much nicer to have them paired so that the first a event would arrive with the first b event.

Comment: I think you'd better ask this question on the Rx forums.

Comment: Do you need an output after _every_ value emitted from the source observables, or just after the first values?

Answer (score 2):

There is a MailboxProcessor in F#... I would use a SynchronizationContext in C# for the same purpose.  Give me a few minutes and I will write up an example.

Aside: Here's my code in F# that does something similar...  It will be considerably more effort, but still doable in C# with Rx.

```
open System.Diagnostics

let numWorkers = 20
let asyncDelay = 100

type MessageForMailbox =
   | DataMessage of AsyncReplyChannel<unit>
   | GetSummary of AsyncReplyChannel<unit>

let main =
   let actor =
      MailboxProcessor.Start( fun inbox ->
         let rec loop acc =
            async {
               let! message = inbox.Receive()
               match message with
               | DataMessage replyChannel -> replyChannel.Reply(); return! loop acc
               | GetSummary replyChannel -> replyChannel.Reply(); return! loop acc
            }

         loop 0 // seed for acc
      )

   let codeBlocks = [for i in 1..numWorkers -> 
                        async {
                           do! Async.Sleep asyncDelay
                           return! actor.PostAndAsyncReply DataMessage
                        } ]

   while true do
      printfn "Concurrent started..."
      let sw = new Stopwatch()
      sw.Start()
      codeBlocks |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore
      actor.PostAndReply GetSummary
      sw.Stop()
      printfn "Concurrent in %d millisec" sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
      printfn "efficiency: %d%%" (int64 (asyncDelay * 100) / sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)

      printfn "Synchronous started..."
      let sw = new Stopwatch()
      sw.Start()
      for codeBlock in codeBlocks do codeBlock |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore
      sw.Stop()
      printfn "Synchronous in %d millisec" sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
      printfn "efficiency: %d%%" (int64 (asyncDelay * numWorkers * 100) / sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)

main
```

Comment: hmm, so you mean something along the lines of using SynchronizationContext.Send() to sync all the observables creating Events? I kinda see what your F# code does but I'm not savvy enough to understand it completely.

Comment: I think you got it.  RunSynchronously implements ForkJoin with async workflows.

Comment: +1: I've never seen a good example of the MailboxProcessor before. :)